# pandas: change table structue

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I want to change my table structure for plotting

Input:

|  | Year | Company | Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2006 | ABC | 500 |
| 1 | 2007 | ABC | 700 |
| 2 | 2007 | PQR | 800 |
| 3 | 2006 | PQR | 600 |
| 4 | 2006 | ABC | 500 |

to output:

| Year | ABC | PQR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2006 | 1000 | 600 |
| 2007 | 700 | 800 |

In addition to sum, i also want to take log of the sum. For eg in Year=2006, under column ABC, i want 3 (log1000). Similarly, for other columns as well.

I tried aggfunc=math.log(np.sum) in pivot_table but this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df.pivot_table(index='Year', columns='Company', values='Number',
               aggfunc=lambda x: np.log10(np.sum(x)))
```

output:

```
Company       ABC       PQR
Year                       
2006     3.000000  2.778151
2007     2.845098  2.903090
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
>>> df.pivot_table('Number', *df.columns[:-1], aggfunc=sum)
Company   ABC  PQR
Year              
2006     1000  600
2007      700  800
>>>
```

Or:

```
>>> df.pivot_table('Number', 'Year', 'Company', aggfunc=sum)
Company   ABC  PQR
Year              
2006     1000  600
2007      700  800
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer to questions

1. Difference between pivot and pivot_table

You already pick the right direction but there is a little difference:
`pivot` will raise ValueError if index/columns pair is not unique. In your case,
both row in index 0 and index 4 share the same Year/Company pair "2006 ABC",
use `pivot_table` as a generalization of pivot.

See note at the end of section [reshaping](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-pivoting-dataframe-objects) for more details.

2. Apply function to DataFrame

You cannot apply function in chain by concat them directly, by using
`math.log(numpy.sum)` you instruct python to return a log of function object,
but what you want is a log of **the result** of that function object, that is difference.

Instead, the pivot table returned is a new DataFrame object, which is suitable
to apply your log function like the following way:

pseudo code:

```
df = read(input)
df2 = pivot(df)
df3 = df2['some_column_index'].apply(func1).apply(func2).[...apply(funcN)]
```

see [Function application](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#function-application) for more details.

### Code example

A complete code like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# read data from input

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', sep=', ', index_col=0)

# pivot your input DataFrame and return a new one

df2 = df.pivot_table(index="Year", columns="Company", values="Number", aggfunc=np.sum)

# operate log function on df2

logyear = df2.apply(np.log10)

# update df2

df2.update(logyear)

# display

df2
```